# angularjs ui-sortable: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I'm trying to do sorting list, I take the element from the db but...

> Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

My html:

```
<div class="box-body" >
    <div ng:controller="menuConfigCtrl">
        <ul ui-sortable ng-model="menu"  >
            <li ng:repeat="item in menu |filter:'all' | orderBy:'order':false" >{{item.Title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
function menuConfigCtrl($location,$scope, menuFactory) {    
    $scope.menu = [];
    menuFactory.getMenu().success(function(data){
        $scope.menu = data;
    }); 
}
```

My `getMenu()` is:

```
getMenu : function(){
    return $http({
        url: '/api/menuList',
        method: 'GET',
    });
},
```

If I get the menu not from a rest service, but binding it, everything work without error!
What can be?

---

**Problem solved:** I imported `angularjs.js` twice.

Comment: Have you tried calling `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.menu = data;`

Comment: yes, and it return
 $digest already in progress and then.
cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: I cant reproduce, can you create a fiddle that shows the issue ?   Could start from here: http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/MRUDW/

Comment: the problem is that it return error just if i take my menu from a rest serive! so i don't know how to replace it..

Comment: @jusBorn I updated my fiddle, and still cant' reproduce ur issue.  I plugged in a mock service, as well as the angular ui-sortable ... please try again, and if you can't reproduce we will need to close the question.

Comment: i solved the problems
i was including 2 times the angular.js...
and so the app was read two times! thank so much!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo

Comment: @justBorn you should reply to your own question and accept the answer to mark it resolved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved: I imported angularjs.js twice.